# Get list of all courses, Wordpress php leardash

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins

I'm new to Wordpress and I need to get the list of all courses with PHP from the plugin Learndash but impossible for far to find I can get it.

If one of you can save me thx.

Comment: If you want a more specific answer consider adding the url to the plugins website or an url to the documentation of the plugin.

Answer (score 0):

Most of the plugins don't offer php functions or an api to query their data. I mostly were at this point, where the only solution is to query/edit the data manually in the mysql database of wordpress. You have to search for the table(s) where the plusing stores the data. Then you can access the data using the `mysqli` php functions by connecting to the database and querying the data using `sql`.

Hope it helps you!

Answer (score 0):

This is like two years old, but I'm having a similar issue. There are two things that are working for me:

```
1.) <?php echo(do_shortcode("[ld_course_list col='4']"));  ?> 
2.) select * from wp_posts where post_type = "sfwd-courses" ;
```

where 2 can be further translated into

```
[posts_table post_type="sfwd-courses"]
```

1. Looks like you sort of have to go with their defaults, and/or CSS style the crap out of it. [2 seems to have a bunch more options](https://barn2.co.uk/list-learndash-courses-lessons-table/).

I think there's an underlying API here, since there are [REST examples](https://developers.learndash.com/rest-api/v2/v2-courses/). I'm not sure what it is, yet, though.

I'll update this as I find more solutions.